# using MongoDB C# Driver order Document Fields with inherited type objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, c#-4.0, bson

I have the following two classes in my C# and I am using BsonElement for property order in Mongo Collection. But Car collection doesn't implement this order.

Idea here is to have this common field in `BaseEntity` class and inherit this on almost all classes

```
public class Car: BaseEntity{
   [BsonElement(Order = 1)]
   public string Color{ get; set; }
   [BsonElement(Order = 2)]
   public long Price{ get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity{
   [BsonElement(Order = 99)]
   public DateTime DateAdded{ get; set; }
   [BsonElement(Order = 100)]
   public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}
```

Car collection in Mongo turns out to be as following. Base class properties are coming first in the document and child class though I have `BsonElement(Order=xx)`

```
{
   "_id" :ObjectId(fsdfsdfsdfsdfs),
   "DateAdded": ISO("SomeDate"),
   "IsActive" : true,
   "Color" : "Red",
   "Price" : NumberLong(23564)
}
```

I wand this to look like

```
{
   "_id" :ObjectId(fsdfsdfsdfsdfs),
   "Color" : "Red",
   "Price" : NumberLong(23564)
   "DateAdded": ISO("SomeDate"),
   "IsActive" : true
}
```

Driver details

```
  <package id="mongocsharpdriver" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: The order makes senses, since you are implementing inheritance...that's why the base class orders first...the only way to overrides this, should be to implement a class that overrides BsonElement...but, since your class is so small, why the inheritance, or you are just doing that for practice purposes?

Comment: This is a example code, I have about 8 Properties in Base class that needs to be inherited in all Mongo Collections (classes) and Yes it is for practice as well. If I have 8 Collection classes I don't want to repeat this base class properties in 8 child classes

Comment: Just for testing: and if you remove Order from the base class?

Comment: No Difference with or with out Order

Comment: That's weird....according to the docs `Any fields or properties that do not have an explicit Order will occur after those that do have an Order.`

Comment: Interesting. doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will not fall into expected answer, but attributes used inside class are respected there, that means serializer builds final class using it base elements first, then elements from concrete object.

To test that, I created class bus:car

```
public class Bus:Car{
[BsonElement(Order = 1)]
   public string BusColor{ get; set; }
   [BsonElement(Order = 2)]
   public long BusPrice{ get; set; }
}
```

and output just confirmed that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5799eb7c1751a60613b36cbc"),
    "DateAdded" : ISODate("2016-07-28T11:24:44.222Z"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "Color" : "Black-White",
    "Price" : NumberLong(923),
    "BusColor" : "Blue",
    "BusPrice" : NumberLong(12345)
}
```

What kind of problem are you going to solve with that sorting?

Any comments welcome!

==========

## EDIT

found that in bson driver source code

```
 private void OrderMembers()
    {
        // only auto map properties declared in this class (and not in base classes)
        var hasOrderedElements = false;
        var hasUnorderedElements = false;
        foreach (var memberMap in _declaredMemberMaps)
        {
            if (memberMap.Order != int.MaxValue)
            {
                hasOrderedElements |= true;
            }
            else
            {
                hasUnorderedElements |= true;
            }
        }

        if (hasOrderedElements)
        {
            if (hasUnorderedElements)
            {
                // split out the unordered elements and add them back at the end (because Sort is unstable, see online help)
                var unorderedElements = new List<BsonMemberMap>(_declaredMemberMaps.Where(pm => pm.Order == int.MaxValue));
                _declaredMemberMaps.RemoveAll(m => m.Order == int.MaxValue);
                _declaredMemberMaps.Sort((x, y) => x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order));
                _declaredMemberMaps.AddRange(unorderedElements);
            }
            else
            {
                _declaredMemberMaps.Sort((x, y) => x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: AS I explained in my question, I want base class properties to be at the last. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Well its display order in JSON document on Mongo Queries, I don't want those fields to show up on top, we have to scroll for each result to get to the specific record details